# Products of quadratic forms

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

It is known that, if $x_1^2 + y_1^2 = c_1$ and $x_2^2 + y_2^2 = c_2$, then $(x_1x_2 + y_1y_2)^2 + (x_1y_2 - x_2y_1)^2 = c_1 c_2$

Is there a similar analogue for general quadratic forms $Q(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$?

Comment: "Indirect" reasoning (maybe wrong!): if yes,it would already be a quite known theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual generalization of this may not be what you expect. Your example concerns the principal form of discriminant $-4,$ and is the earliest example of Gauss composition.

There is a similar item, I think the name Brahmagupta is used in this regard,
$$ (u^2 + n v^2)(x^2 + n y^2) = (ux \pm nvy)^2 + n(uy \mp vx)^2.  $$

More generally, your $\langle a,b,c\rangle $ and $\langle a,-b,c\rangle $ are inverses in the class group of forms with the same discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4 a c$ and $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1.$  If $\Delta \geq 0,$ it is not allowed to be $0$ or $1$ or any other square, that way leads to madness.

Maybe i should just give Dirichlet's version of composition; given two "united" forms. This is in the book by [Cox, Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2$](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118390180.html), in the first edition page 49: given integer constants $a,a',B,C,$ with requirement $\gcd(a,a',B)=1,$ and integer variables $x,y,z,w,$ the composition identity is
$$ (a x^2 + Bxy+ a'Cy^2)(a'z^2 + B zw+ a C w^2) = a a' X^2 + BXY +CY^2,  $$
with new variables
$$ X = xz - C yw; \; \; Y = axw + a'yz + B yw. $$
Let me check that, i think there is a typo in the book, just one letter. Yes, what I typed here is correct, one letter wrong in that book. Good, corrected in the [SECOND EDITION](https://books.google.com/books?id=NklYBAAAQBAJ&pg=SA3-PA7&lpg=SA3-PA7&dq=cox%20primes%20of%20the%20form%20%22composition%20identity%22&source=bl&ots=WyYXQHk6M3&sig=rsOKRglwwogVOhyluMZuaYK6PM0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dZxoVZvIGYzSoATFmILACQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=cox%20primes%20of%20the%20form%20%22composition%20identity%22&f=false)

You also need to know about reducing forms to make much sense of this. 
However, if $C=1,$ we see "opposite" forms composing into the principal form (it integrally represents $1$, and is the multiplicative identity in the group). If, instead, $B=0, a=a'=1,$ we get Brahmagupta.

In case anyone gets interested, my favorite book on binary quadratic forms is [BUELL](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387970370); Dirichlet's brief composition law is on page 57. Most of the discussion is on how to get two forms of the same discriminant into this useful format.

Comment: In this mentioned book, I found the product form in case of $x^2 + ny^2$. It should be sufficient at least for now.