# Consider the following Diophantine equation: $x^2 + xy + y^2 = n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, prime-factorization

Consider the following Diophantine equation
$$x^2 + xy + y^2 = n\,.$$
For a particular positive integer $n$, the number of solutions $\left(x,y\right)$ such that $x$ and $y$ are integers is given by the function $S(n)$.

The function $S(n)$ is not one-to-one. For example, each number $n$ in the set $$\{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36\}$$ corresponds with $S(n) = 6$.

In increasing order, starting from $n = 1$, the first $n$ such that $S(n) = 36$ is $637$.

> What is the $500$th $n$ such that $S(n) = 36$?

Any precise approach or hint from where I should start the problem?

Comment: I would have write $(x+y)^2=n-2xy$. See if it can leads you

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: @EDX surely the RHS would be n+xy no? I hope I'm not making a fool of myself

Comment: Since $x^2+xy+y^2=\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2+3\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2$ we need to consider ring $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, where $\omega=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. This numbers are called Eisenstein integers, if I'm not mistaken and your question is how to find number of solutions of the equation $N(z)=n$.

Comment: The solutions are well understood, you should start there: [The set of integers $n$ expressible with $n=x^2+xy+y^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843675/the-set-of-integers-n-expressible-with-n-x2xyy2)

Comment: Yes of course cc

Comment: Actually $S(637)=36$, while $S(636)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $S$ corresponds to OEIS sequence [A004016](https://oeis.org/A004016).
From there you can get several implementations, for example in PARI:

```
 {a(n) = if( n<1, n==0, 6 * sumdiv( n, d, (d%3==1) - (d%3==2)))}; /* Michael Somos, May 20 2005 */
 k=0; for (n=1, oo, if (a(n)==36, print (k++ " " n); if (k==500, break)))
```