# Number of unordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+3xy+y^2=n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $\mathbb{Z}^+$ denote the set of positive integers, and let $P(x,y)=x^2+3xy+y^2$.

If $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, let $\delta(n)$ be the number of unordered pairs
$(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^+\times\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $P(x,y)=n$.

With the help of a computer program, I have verified that :

$\bullet$ $\delta(2299)=\delta(3509)=\delta(3751)=\delta(3971)=3$

$\bullet$ $\delta(n)=2$ for $n\in E_2$, with

$E_2=\{209, 319, 341, 451, 551, 589, 605, 649, 671, 779, 781, 836, 869, 899, 979, 1045, 1111, 1121, 1159, 1189, 1199, 1271, 1276 1331, 1349, 1364, 1441, 1501, 1529, 1595, 1639, 1661, 1691, 1705, 1711, 1769, 1804, 1805, 1829, 1881, 1891, 1919, 1969, 1991, 2059, 2071, 2101, 2189, 2201, 2204, 2255, 2291, 2321, 2356, 2419, 2420, 2449, 2489, 2501, 2519, 2581, 2596, 2629, 2641, 2651, 2684, 2755, 2759, 2761, 2831, 2869, 2871, 2911, 2929, 2945, 2959, 2981, 3069, 3091, 3116, 3124, 3131, 3161, 3239, 3245, 3344, 3355, 3379, 3401, 3421, 3439, 3476, 3596, 3599, 3629, 3641, 3649, 3781, 3799, 3839, 3895, 3905, 3916,  3949\}$

$\bullet$ $\delta(n)\in\{0;1\}$ for all other values of $n\leqslant4000$.

Using the identity

$$P(x,y)P(z,w)=P(yw-xz,yw+xz+3xw),$$

I managed to prove that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\delta(n)=+\infty.$

but I am sure we can do much better. For example, is there a way to express $\delta(n)$ in terms of $n$ ?

Comment: it is about factoring $n.$  Your $\delta = 1$  should be for primes $5$ and $p \equiv 1,4 \pmod 5.$    Then $\delta = 2$  for $pq .$  My memory is that multiplying by $5$   does not change the count, not sure. Note $2299 = 11 \cdot 11 \cdot 19$  Finally, multiplying by $4$ or by any $q^2$  with  $q \equiv 2,3 \pmod 5.$

Comment: Simple lemma: if $n$ is divisible by any prime $q \equiv2,3 \pmod 5$  and the exponent  for $q$ is odd, then $n$ is not represented.  If the exponent of $q$  is even,  the number of representations of $n$  is the same as the number of representations of $n/q^2$

Comment: Do you think we can calculate $\delta(n)$ based on the prime factor decomposition of $n$ ?
It is thanks to your answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1304110/products-of-quadratic-forms) that I was able to find the above identity.

Comment: Oh, yes. Your identity is Gauss composition, available in many books. Also,   given $x,y$  with one of them negative, one may move by repeated use of either  direction: $P(x,y) = P(-y,x+3y) $  or  $P(x,y) = P(3x+y,-x) $  to arrive at $x,y > 0$

Comment: Oh,   with $P(x,y) = P(y,x)$ if needed